# How to set infoWindow content from an array Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am trying to populate infowindow content from an array:

```
var arrayTest = ["a", "b"];
infoWindow.setContent("<p>Header</p>" + arrayTest.map(function (val) { return "<p>" + val + "</p>" }));
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

The following is returned:

[image]

How do I prevent the comma from being printed within the infoWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.join()` method to change your concatenation default char that is the comma

```
var arrayTest = ["a", "b"];
infoWindow.setContent("<p>Header</p>" + arrayTest.map(function (val) { return "<p>" + val + "</p>" }).join(""));
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array.  So for your example:

```
arrayTest.map(function (val) { return "<p>" + val + "</p>" })
```

will return: `["<p>a</p>","<p>b</p>"];` (with the comma in it).

You can use [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to combine that array into a string without the comma: `"<p>Header</p><p>a</p><p>b</p>"`

```
arrayTest.map(function (val) { return "<p>" + val + "</p>" }).join("")
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/co7y1tL3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
"use strict";

// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.
function initMap() {
  const uluru = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044,
  };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru,
  });

const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var arrayTest = ["a", "b"];
infoWindow.setContent("<p>Header</p>" + arrayTest.map(function (val) { return "<p>" + val + "</p>" }).join(""));
const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map,
    title: "Uluru (Ayers Rock)",
  });
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
marker.addListener("click", () => {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Info Windows</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```